# Ember observer not working on nested property

Tags: ember.js, observers

I have created a mock application to illustrate the situation I am facing: [Mock App](https://ember-twiddle.com/7315c32e07bc3d4f964c94e09d758a2c?openFiles=components.toggle-observer.js%2C)

In this application; I have created a service with a single boolean property and a function to toggle that property (`x`); and two components (one to toggle the service's property; the other to observe the number of toggles and display it). The observer lies in `toggle-observer`. It is added directly to service's property as: `myService.x`. The code is not working as is; however if the comment at line 14 of  `toggle-observer.js` is commented out; the observer starts working.

My question is that, do I need to perform a `get` to the whole path of a nested observer property to get it working? Is this the expected behavior? If so, can somebody explain why? My best regards.

Note: This is a mock example to illustrate the case; it is not related to anything I am designing in a real app. I am trying to avoid observers as much as possible; but I ran into this situation while trying out sth. and decided to ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ember guide [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/applications/services/#toc_defining-services)

> Injected properties are lazy loaded; meaning the service will not be
>   instantiated until the property is explicitly called. Therefore you
>   need to access services in your component using the get function
>   otherwise you might get an undefined.

From ember guide, [unconsumed computed properties do not trigger observers](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/observers/#toc_unconsumed-computed-properties-do-not-trigger-observers). 
By combining the above two concepts, we can come to the below conclusion,

You haven't used `myService` any of the property inside `toggle-observer` component so it will be `undefined` until you explicitly call `get` function or use it in template.

Unless you use it `x` property in `toggle-observer` component, then it will not trigger observer. You need to consume it either in toggle-observer.hbs file or in `init` method.

Comment: Thanks for the response; only the part related with injected properties being lazy is valid; because I do not have any unconsumed computed property in my code. nevertheless; i would have expected the code to work as is; because just getting the service without doing anything with it fixes the case.