# Ember - ensure that bindings work when setting properties in callback of a custom AJAX function

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I am getting some unpredictable behaviour when setting an Ember property in the callback of a custom AJAX function.

The AJAX function is fired in the route as shown below. The success callback updates the property 'session.ajaxStatus' from 'checking' to 'success'. This happens correctly every time a success response is received, and the console logs 'route: success' from the callback function.

The problem is that I am trying to observe and react to that property in a component. Sometimes this observer recognises that 'session.ajaxStatus' has updated from 'checking' to 'success' but sometimes it doesn't.

My guess is that this has to do with how long it takes for the response to be returned. I have wrapped by AJAX function in Ember.run as recommended, to try and ensure that it happens in the Ember run loop.

Is there something I can do to ensure that the observer binding always works, or should I revise the entire pattern?

Route:

```js
session: Ember.inject.service(),

...

actions: {
  ajaxRequest: function() {
    Ember.run(this, function() {
      var self = this;
      var url = self.get('session.url');
      self.set('session.ajaxStatus', 'checking');
      console.log('route: ' + self.get('session.ajaxStatus'));
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
          console.log('success response');
          callBack(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
          self.set('session.ajaxStatus', 'error');
        }
      });
      callBack = function(jobsInLicense) {
        self.set('session.ajaxStatus', 'success');
        console.log('route: ' + self.get('session.ajaxStatus'));
        //Always logs 'route: success'.
      };
    });
  },
}
```

Component:

```js
session: Ember.inject.service(),

checkAjaxStatus: function() {
  console.log('component: ' + this.get('session.ajaxStatus'));
  //Sometimes nothing is logged.
}.observes('session.ajaxStatus'),
```

Comment: Where are you using/consuming `session.ajaxStatus` property ?

Comment: It is used in the component, to determine various settings for the UI- for example a loading spinner is shown until session.ajaxStatus is 'success', after which the content is shown.

Comment: checkAjaxStatus: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('session.ajaxStatus', function() { ... }))

Comment: Refer [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41938581/5771666) for hiccups. if you could provide related component and template hbs. then it would be useful to confirm `session` service is used/created before calling ajax request

Comment: I can definitely confirm that the session service is used before the AJAX call- the variable 'url' which is the url for the AJAX request is obtained from the session service- var url = self.get('session.url');.
I also tried chekmare's approach and that also had the same problem. I even tried putting {{session.ajaxStatus}} in the component HBS file, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible you can avoid using observer for this. it depends what actions you are going to perform in `checkAjaxStatus`

For your question,
Inside route, you don't need to wrap it in `Ember.run`.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service(),
    actions: {
        actions: {
            ajaxRequest() {
                var self = this;
                var url = self.get('session.url');
                self.set('session.ajaxStatus', 'checking');
                Ember.$.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                }).then(function(response) {
                    self.set('session.ajaxStatus', 'success');
                }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    self.set('session.ajaxStatus', 'error');
                })
            },
        }
    }
});
```

And your component code,

```
session: Ember.inject.service(),

checkAjaxStatus: Ember.observer('session.ajaxStatus', function() {
        console.log('component: ' + this.get('session.ajaxStatus'));
        //Sometimes nothing is logged.
    }),
```

and include `{{session.ajaxStatus}}` inside component hbs code.

I tried in [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6b6536d94a0e01c1a8264a90079791ca?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs), you can have look into this.

Comment: @AJP when I run your code in twiddle it shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: callBack is not defined`  Since callback is defined later after using it.

Comment: Thank you- this is correct. Actually what was happening is that the AJAX request was fired during a transition. Sometimes, [self.set('session.ajaxStatus', 'success');] had already run before my component had been inserted, thus there was no change to observe. I simply use code in didInsertElement to check if 'session.ajaxStatus equals 'success' and react accordingly.

Comment: Just reminder, didInsertElement will be called only once for the first render alone.

Comment: Yes absolutely- so my observer is still there in the component- so if session.ajaxStatus only updates from 'checking' to 'success' after the component is inserted, then the observer fires.